# Showing fastest ETA in REAL TIME

Tags: android, real-time, google-directions-api

I want to show the ETA(Estimated time of arrival) in real time,Which means as the vehicle moves i need to get the ETA and distance similar to OLA.I can do this using google directions api,But my problem is usage limit of the api. Please let me know if there is any other better approach or efficient usage of google direction api.